# Monitoring Windows 2003 Server scheduled task running time

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, system-monitoring

I've been trying to find solution/script to monitor Windows Server 2003 scheduled task running time. I can list details of the tasks via cmd:

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST /v
```

Is it possible to create for example batch script which calculates running time of the task?

Answer (score 0):

Tough to find anything specific as to a "Run Time" for a scheduled task.
But, what I found is you can put some type of script together to monitor Event logs for Source: TaskScheduler TaskID: 102 (or other eventIDs) which for me on Windows 7 is the event for the time a task finished.

Only option I can see right now is I'd put together a script basically that locates the time a Scheduled Task event starts and then finishes.

Comment: Actually I've done this with PowerShell using `Win-Event` cmdlet, `TaskScheduler/Operational` log and `EventId`'s 100 and 102: [Windows Task Scheduler Chart?](http://superuser.com/a/885017/418201). But it works only for Vista and higher.

Comment: Found this today:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/2003_Server/Q_23282301.html

Open tasks and look for the Advanced menu option. Look for "View Log". That might contain the information you are looking for.

I also found that the SchedLgu.txt is not visible, so one of these options below might help you locate it.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic142809-5-1.aspx
http://windowsxp.mvps.org/schedlog.htm